Curl produces different behaviour under the same request
I was using curl in linux in the command line to access different websites. At one point I noticed that something seemed odd when making request to linkedin. I ran this script to store and check the responses.
# First request
curl -o response1.html https://www.linkedin.com/

# Second request
sleep 5
curl -o response2.html https://www.linkedin.com/

# Compare
icdiff response1.html response2.html

The icdiff showed that there was a good chunk of information, but even better because I stored it as an HTML I saw the display on my web browser where the difference became very clear. Since I can't post the image I will post a brief chunk of the HTML
    </div>                                                                     
                                                                               
        </div>                                                                 
                                                                               
<!---->                                                                        
        <div class="sign-in-form__divi                                         
der left-right-divider pt-1 pb-3">                                             
          <p class="sign-in-form__divi                                         
der-text font-sans text-sm text-color-                                         
text px-2">                                                                    
            or                                                                 
          </p>                                                                 
        </div>                                                                 
    <form data-id="sign-in-form" actio                                         
n="https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login-                                         
submit" method="post" novalidate data-                                         
js-module-id="d2l-sign-in-form">                                               
      <input name="loginCsrfParam" val                                         
ue="a2b3c0d0-9bcf-4d31-8a16-f2a7ceb801                                         
1e" type="hidden">                                                             
                                                                               
      <div class="flex flex-col">                                              
                                                                               
    <div class="mt-1.5" data-js-module                                         
-id="guest-input">                                                             
      <div class="flex flex-col">                                              
        <label class="input-label mb-1                                         
" for="session_key">                                                           
          Email or phone                                                       
        </label>                                                               
        <div class="text-input flex">                                          
          <input class="text-color-tex                                         
t font-sans text-md outline-0 bg-color                                         
-transparent grow" autocomplete="usern                                         
ame" id="session_key" name="session_ke                                         
y" required data-tracking-control-name                                         
="homepage-basic_sign-in-session-key"                                          
data-tracking-client-ingraph type="tex                                         
t">                                                                            
                                                                               
        </div>                                                                 
      </div>                                                                   
                                                                               
      <p class="input-helper mt-1.5" f                                         
or="session_key" role="alert" data-js-                                         
module-id="guest-input__message"></p>                                          
    </div>                                                                     
                                                                               
                                                                               
                                                                               
    <div class="mt-1.5" data-js-module                                         
-id="guest-input">                                                             
      <div class="flex flex-col">                                              
        <label class="input-label mb-1                                         
" for="session_password">                                                      
          Password                                                             
        </label>                                                               
        <div class="text-input flex">                                          
          <input class="text-color-tex                                         
t font-sans text-md outline-0 bg-color                                         
-transparent grow" autocomplete="curre                                         
nt-password" id="session_password" nam                                         
e="session_password" required data-tra                                         
cking-control-name="homepage-basic_sig                                         
n-in-password" data-tracking-client-in                                         
graph type="password">                                                         
                                                                               
            <button aria-live="asserti                                         
ve" aria-relevant="text" data-id="sign                                         
-in-form__password-visibility-toggle"                                          
class="font-sans text-md font-bold tex                                         
t-color-action z-10 ml-[12px] hover:cu                                         
rsor-pointer" aria-label="Show your Li                                         
nkedIn password" data-tracking-control                                         
-name="homepage-basic_sign-in-password                                         
-visibility-toggle-btn" type="button">                                         
Show</button>                                                                  
                                                                               
        </div>                                                                 
      </div>                                                                   
                                                                               
      <p class="input-helper mt-1.5" f                                         
or="session_password" role="alert" dat                                         
a-js-module-id="guest-input__message">                                         
</p>                                                                           
    </div>                                                                     
                                                                               
                                                                               
        <input name="session_redirect"                                         
 type="hidden">                                                                
                                                                               
<!---->      </div>                                                            
                                                                               
      <div data-id="sign-in-form__foot                                         
er" class="flex justify-between                                                
          sign-in-form__footer--full-w                                         
idth">                                                                         
        <a data-id="sign-in-form__forg                                         
ot-password" class="font-sans text-md                                          
font-bold link leading-regular                                                 
            sign-in-form__forgot-passw                                         
ord--full-width" href="https://www.lin                                         
kedin.com/uas/request-password-reset?t                                         
rk=homepage-basic_forgot_password" dat                                         
a-tracking-control-name="homepage-basi                                         
c_forgot_password" data-tracking-will-                                         
navigate>Forgot password?</a>                                                  
                                                                               
<!---->                                                                        
        <input name="trk" value="homep                                         
age-basic_sign-in-submit" type="hidden                                         
">                                                                             
        <button class="btn-md btn-prim                                         
ary flex-shrink-0 cursor-pointer                                               
            sign-in-form__submit-btn--                                         
full-width" data-id="sign-in-form__sub                                         
mit-btn" data-tracking-control-name="h                                         
omepage-basic_sign-in-submit-btn" data                                         
-tracking-client-ingraph data-tracking                                         
-litms type="submit">                                                          
          Sign in                                                              
        </button>                                                              
      </div>                                                                   
<!---->    </form>                                                             
<!---->       

Almost all of this was missing on the second response. Visually is pretty clear that both pages have different login sections.
Normally when you do a request of a page you expect the same behaviour. My questions then are, why did the contents of the response changed although the request was the same? Is this something normal? Can it be fixed?
I appreciate the help.

I can't reproduce this! After my tries, both file show same size. only diff are in generated Unique IDs. diff response*|wc: 8      40    1148.

Are you behind a proxy?

Can you reproduce the effect with a website, where you can be sure that it will serve the identical content on every request?

No I am not behind a proxy and I've only seen this happen in that particular website I can't seem to replicate it on other websites which makes it more strange. At this point I'm wondering if it's a problem of that site

If the server returns different results to the same request, that's an issue with the server, not your code. Most likely it's some kind of rate limiting.

We might not be able to reproduce it because we haven't been querying the site as many times as you have during your testing.

LinkedIn has an API, they discourage web scraping like this (it may even be against their TOS).

Yeah I figured it was most likely an issue with the site since I tried to check the same behaviour in sites like wikipedia, etc... and did not work. And yeah I have been querying the site a lot trying to analize what was happening. For now I'll just go with Barmar comments and assume it's a problem or characteristic (if you don't want to see it as a problem) of that sire

You should also consider A/B testing
